# Error: Code=InvalidServiceName | 9.2 PAAS set-up

Tags: installation, paas, arm-template

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.2 Standalone on Azure PAAS using **Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410**.

I am following the steps provided at https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--deploying-a-new-sitecore-environment-to-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html

I am facing an issue here as the script breaks after the provisioning state is marked as a success.

The last log:

```
VERBOSE: 9:45:02 AM - Created resource group 'october-2019' in location 'eastasia'
```

After that my resource details are displayed on th screen.

Then I got this error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:00:02 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'october-2019' is not valid according to the validation
procedure. The tracking id is 'c301cb8c-5e23-4e5e-8740-76ee6df2c747'. See inner errors for details.
At D:\Personal\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:117 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:00:02 AM - Error: Code=InvalidServiceName; Message=Service name '-as' is invalid: Service name must only contain lowercase letters, digits or
dashes, cannot start or end with or contain consecutive dashes and is limited to 60 characters.
At D:\Personal\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:117 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At D:\Personal\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.3.0 rev. 190410\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:117 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

The following are the different combinations which I tried:

1. Oct
2. October
3. Oct-2019
4. October2019
5. october2019
6. october-2019
7. 20191003

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: You'll get this if you're not passing the "deploymentId" parameter

Comment: @MarkGibbons: Please provide your comment in answer, so I can accept it. I was thinking that as I have provided it in the Powershell interface, it's fine, as the logs were showing that value.  I populated it in the azuredeploy.parameters.json and was able to move ahead. The log was misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this if the `deploymentId` parameter is somehow not being set correctly.

The key error message you provided:

> Service name '-as' is invalid

This is the Azure Search resource name, which is prepended by the `deploymentId` parameter.

The [Sitecore Azure Quickstart Templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.2.0/XPSingle) says

> The deploymentId and licenseXml parameters in azuredeploy.parameters.json are filled in by the PowerShell script using Name and LicenseXmlPath parameters respectively.